# Как вывести текст на странице таксономии?

Tags: wordpress

Есть кастомная таксономия "МЕТРО" которая выводиться через файл taxonomy-metro.php .

```
<?php if ( have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); // если посты есть - запускаем цикл wp ?>
    <?php get_template_part('loop'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php ?>
    <?php endwhile; // конец цикла
    else: echo '<br><h2>Пока в данном разделе отсутстувуют записи, возможно вас заинтересуют записи из других категорий</h2><br>';
      $recent3 = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'showposts'=> '10',
        'posts_per_page' => '10'
        )
      );
      while($recent3->have_posts()) : $recent3->the_post() ;    ?>
    <?php get_template_part('loop'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
 <?php wp_reset_query() ; ?>
      <?php endif; // если записей нет, напишим "простите" ?>   
    <?php pagination();  // пагинация, функция нах-ся в function.php ?>
```

На страницах текст выводил через the_content(), а вот на странице таксономии не получается.

Comment: term_description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для простых текстов (включая форматирование) можно использовать описание таксономии выводя с помощью [term_description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_description/)

Для более сложных конструкций используются произвольные поля или даже связи межу таксономией и типом контента.